Promtail parsing log writing to cnosdb failed
Promtail parsing log writing to cnosdb failed. The error log as follow:
ts=2024-09-05T03:25:54.996434Z caller=client.go:430 component=client host=localhost:8902 msg="final error sending batch" status=422 tenant= error="server returned HTTP status 422 Unprocessable Entity (422): {\"error_code\":\"040016\",\"error_message\":\"Error parsing log message: invalid log syntax: parse_protobuf_to_lokilog error: failed to decode Protobuf message: Entry.line: Stream.entries: PushRequest.streams: invalid string value: data is not UTF-8 encoded\"}"

How should this be solved? My configuration file is as follows
server:
  http_listen_port: 9080
  grpc_listen_port: 0

positions:
  filename: /tmp/positions.yaml

clients:
  - url: http://localhost:8902/api/v1/es/_bulk?db=prometail&table=table4&log_type=loki
    basic_auth:
      username: root
      password:

scrape_configs:
- job_name: system
  static_configs:
  - targets:
      - localhost
    labels:
      job: varlogs
      __path__: /var/log/*log
      stream: stdout

Parse macos logs and write them to cnosdb.
